# Trying to convert to EPSG:27700 (Ordnance Survey) projection, unable to do so

Tags: wfs, coordinate-system, well-known-text, ordnance-survey

I'm trying to code an interface that allows a user to draw a vector shape on openstreetmap, which is then converted to a WKT string, processed by the server and sent of as a WFS query to emapsite (which provide the Ordnance Survey data, including a veru detailed vector layer of the UK). However the issue I'm having is that when I draw a polygon around all of the UK (which should obviously return data), I'm not getting data returned (as in the server says there are no vectors there). However when I draw a polygon in the south-west corner of Africa (just off the coast of Nigeria), I'm getting a huge amount of data returned. Ordnance Survey uses EPSG:27700 (OSM uses EPSG:90013), which I don't really understand, but I imagine that I'm not doing projection conversions that are necessary. code below:

http://pastebin.com/wi4CUAmc

Comment: Use Openlayers you can re-project your requests on the fly - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8196/reproject-a-vector-layer-epsg27700-using-wfs-onto-a-googlemaps-background-ep

Comment: Can you post some of your code - your other question would get better answers http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62531/how-to-convert-drawn-vector-feature-from-epsg900913-to-epsg4326 or live link to what you have been trying.

Comment: which server are you using

Comment: pastebin: http://pastebin.com/wi4CUAmc

Comment: Apache on a LAMP stack, emapsite is the wms/wfs provider

Comment: looks like you need proj4js to make epsg:27700 work and you don't seem to actually use the variable anyway